# subclassing models.Manager

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I see no difference in sub classing the `models.manager` object and overriding the `get_query_set` method or simply creating a new method in the sub class and using the method. For the reason being I have taken example from the django book;

```
class MaleManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(MaleManager, self).get_query_set().filter(sex='M')
class FemaleManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(FemaleManager, self).get_query_set().filter(sex='F')
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female')))
    people = models.Manager()
    men = MaleManager()
    women = FemaleManager()
```

With this I could use; `Person.women.all()` or `Person.men.all()` to fetch all the men or women model object. But, I guess the similar thing can be achieved without overriding the `get_query_set` method by simply doing;

```
class MaleManager(models.Manager):
    def get_male(self):
        return self.filter(sex='M')
class FemaleManager(models.Manager):
    def get_female(self):
        return  return self.filter(sex='F')
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female')))
    people = models.Manager()
    men = MaleManager()
    women = FemaleManager()
```

Now, with this, I can fetch all those objects with a little technique like;
`Person.objects.get_male()` or `Person.objects.get_female()`. But, there's no any subtle difference between how I could fetch the objects yet there is difference in terms of readability and use in first case while the second one is much easier to understand and has lesser code.Do they make some significant difference in coding and patterns ? The other thing with the second one, what if I place both the methods inside a same class like;

```
class PeopleManager(models.Manager):
        def get_male(self):
            return self.filter(sex='M')
        def get_female(self):
            return  return self.filter(sex='F')
```

Comment: If all you have is 2 methods, the organization afforded by having a completely separate manager isn't worth the trouble - not sure why the django book would suggest a FemaleManager and MaleManager as opposed to a get_females and get_males methods on a single manager.

Comment: It's more depend on your abstraction layer. If you planing to have `PeopleManager` which just separates people by gender second option more usefull. If in future for example `FemaleManager` will have methods like `get_blondes()` or  `get_married()` then the second approach more suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Usually you don't want several managers for the model. It's better to extend default manager.

   ```
   class PeopleManager(models.Manager):
       def get_male(self):
           return self.filter(sex='M')

       def get_female(self):
           return  return self.filter(sex='F')

   class Person(models.Model):
       ....
       objects = PeopleManager()
   ```

   Then you will be able to use `Person.objects.get_male()`, `Person.objects.get_female()` and built-in methods like `Person.objects.order_by()`. You can look at custom managers in `django.contrib.auth.models` for example.
2. `get_query_set` is good for inheritance. For example you can define

   ```
   class SmithManager(PeopleManager):
       def get_queryset(self):
           return super(SmithManager, self).get_query_set().filter(last_name='Smith')
   ```

   and all the methods of the manager will return only Smiths, (`Person.objects.get_male()` will return only males named Smith and so on). And you don't need to rewrite all the methods.

Comment: In this case, in your second point I guess it depends on how I instantiate the object inside my model. If suppose I do objects = models.Manager(), and person = SmithManager(). Then, I am able to use the default objects and the custom that I inherited.

Comment: @insane-36 Any good reason not to just extend default manager? Code with several managers is less clear and harder to maintain. Good advice: forget about managers for a while. Just create your views, forms, other stuff, using normal `objects`. Then analyze the usage and create one good DRY manager that will solve *your tasks*. It will be the best manager.

Comment: Thanks, this topic was interesting one and so I took a while for reviewing this. I will go ahead now.